# How to avoid Spring Cloud Dataflow Source application to keep returning same message

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm suscribing to a Queue on rabbitMQ server and consuming the messages on it to retrieve the body and one particular header. This is done on Spring cloud Dataflow Source application, the issue is when it starts it keeps executing and returning the last message. What do I need to add so the application only execute when a new Message comes to the queue that is listening to?

Here is my Supplier Code:

```
@Log4j2
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ RabbitMQProperties.class })
@Configuration
public class ReceiveMessageConfiguration {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "UniversalId";
    String payload;
    Connection connection;
    Channel channel;


    @Bean
    public Supplier<String> receiverMessage(RabbitMQProperties rabbitMQProperties) throws Exception {
        return () -> {
            try {
                ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
                factory.setHost("localhost");
                factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(0);

                connection = factory.newConnection();
                channel = connection.createChannel();

                channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);

                DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
                    String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
//              Get headers from properties
                    AMQP.BasicProperties properties = delivery.getProperties();
                    Map<String, Object> headers = properties.getHeaders();

//              Extract and print payload and header
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> header : headers.entrySet()) {
                        if (header.getKey().toString().equals("UniversalId")) {
//                      log.info("ID nedeed: " + header.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                    payload = message;
                };
                channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> {
                });
                log.info(payload);
                if (payload != null) {
                    return payload;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                try {
                    channel.close();
                    connection.close();
                } catch (IOException | TimeoutException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return new String("No message");

        };
    }
}
```

My properties file is like this:

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.receiverMessage-in-0=input
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.receiverMessage-out-0=output
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=receiverMessage-input
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=receiverMessage-output
```

Update: Here is an example of the console messages:

```
2022-12-21T16:25:19.725-06:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21600[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mm.c.n.r.RabbitMqCustomSourceApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started RabbitMqCustomSourceApplication in 7.888 seconds (process running for 9.482)
[2m2022-12-21T16:25:20.432-06:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21600[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[   scheduling-1][0;39m [36mm.c.n.r.s.ReceiveMessageConfiguration   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m null
[2m2022-12-21T16:25:21.478-06:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21600[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[   scheduling-1][0;39m [36mm.c.n.r.s.ReceiveMessageConfiguration   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m null
[2m2022-12-21T16:25:22.523-06:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21600[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[   scheduling-1][0;39m [36mm.c.n.r.s.ReceiveMessageConfiguration   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m null
[2m2022-12-21T16:25:23.568-06:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21600[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[   scheduling-1][0;39m [36mm.c.n.r.s.ReceiveMessageConfiguration   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m null
[2m2022-12-21T16:25:24.604-06:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21600[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[   scheduling-1][0;39m [36mm.c.n.r.s.ReceiveMessageConfiguration   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m null
[2m2022-12-21T16:25:25.913-06:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21600[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[   scheduling-1][0;39m [36mm.c.n.r.s.ReceiveMessageConfiguration   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m null
[2m2022-12-21T16:25:27.056-06:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21600[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[   scheduling-1][0;39m [36mm.c.n.r.s.ReceiveMessageConfiguration   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m null
[2m2022-12-21T16:25:28.124-06:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21600[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[   scheduling-1][0;39m [36mm.c.n.r.s.ReceiveMessageConfiguration   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m null
[2m2022-12-21T16:25:29.167-06:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21600[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[   scheduling-1][0;39m [36mm.c.n.r.s.ReceiveMessageConfiguration   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [
    {
        "MailRequest": {
            "action": "fourth",
            "mails": []
        }
    }
]
[2m2022-12-21T16:25:30.233-06:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21600[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[   scheduling-1][0;39m [36mm.c.n.r.s.ReceiveMessageConfiguration   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [
    {
        "MailRequest": {
            "action": "fourth",
            "mails": []
        }
    }
]
```

I already try to change from RabbitMQ API to AMQP API but the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to thanks @onobc for his/her guidence. And also to end this question, what I use to extract specific headers with payload I use the Transform processor default application with a SPeL expression like this: -**-expression="new String(headers.get('LoggerID') + payload)**. Where LoggerID is the name of the header taht you want to extract.

Answer (score 1):

arreola,

Because this is a custom function using Rabbit/AMQP directly, SCDF has no influence. This is therefore more of a Rabbit/AMQP question.

Also, you may want to take a look at the [RabbitSource](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/tree/main/applications/source/rabbit-source) provided application which may serve as a replacement.

Comment: Hi onobc, thanks for the replay, I already check the rabbit source application but at least I'm not able to spot where the suscription to the queue stops. Is there a way to tell Rabbit/AMQP to tell to send this message?

Comment: @Emmanuel_Arreola

It seems like the message is not being acknowledged (even though I see you set autoAck to true in the `basicConsume` call).

The reason you did not find any hints in the RabbitSource is because it leverages Spring Integration to handle pulling in the inbound messages. 

I recommend replacing w/ the provided RabbitSource as it is very robust and likely not have this issue. If you continue w/ your custom source you will most likely continue wanting to add more features which are already in the built-in RabbitSource app.

Comment: @Emmanuel_Arreola another reason to go w/ built-in app is performance. It opens a flux to retrieve the messages but w/ a simple supplier approach it will recreate the connection every poll interval.